# Set up testing-library/react with mocha got SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: babeljs, mocha.js, react-testing-library

I am setting up testing-library/react with mocha. Faced a lot of problems on the setup that were resolved by installing babel libraries and configuring them in `.babelrc` file as explained on the bottom most part of this question. Now, I am stuck on this error:

```
> mocha --exit --require @babel/register --require jsdom-global/register
D:\projects\demo_app\node_modules\antd\es\row\index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Row } from '../grid';
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
```

This comes from ant.design component which uses the syntax above. I have tried to test a dummy component like below:

```js
const component = () => (<div>hello</div>)
```

And it has no problem. But whenever I import my real component that I need to test that is using ant design, I get the error above.
Is it setup part for babel not configured properly? I have no idea how to fix the error. Somehow have a guess that it might be related to babel presets or plugins.

P.S. My project is using Create React App, the exact same test runs smoothly with Jest, but for some reason I don't want to use jest.

Below is .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "esmodules": true,
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ],
    ["@babel/preset-react"]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"],
      "alias": {
        "underscore": "lodash"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Below is package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^4.4.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-google-oauth": "^1.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.1",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "validator": "^13.1.17"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "mocha --exit --require @babel/register --require jsdom-global/register",
    "test:jest": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.12.7",
    "@babel/register": "7.12.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^3.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "husky": "^4.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^16.4.0",
    "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2",
    "mocha": "8.2.1",
    "msw": "^0.19.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "standard": "^14.3.1"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "ignore": [
      "/public"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/?!(react)/"
    ]
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tried to reproduce the issue in codesandbox but could not: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-wiles-cunm1

Comment: Tried to run the code on different machine, get a little bit different error on the same line but with clearer message "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: Cloned the codesandbox code to my machine, ends up with another error: ```D:\projects\babel-bug\node_modules\antd\es\button\index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Button from './button';
                                                                     ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)```

Answer (score 0):

You have `"esmodules": true` which forces Babel to use ES modules. That means that if you're using Node, it needs to support ES modules, and you either need to have your tests in `.mjs` files or have `"type": "module"` in `package.json`. If this isn't supported or you want to support older Node versions, remove `"esmodules": true` from your Babel config to enable compatibility with CJS modules.

Comment: I upgraded NodeJS from v10.15.0 to 14.15.1. And put "type": "module" in package.json. Got new error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:141:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)`

Comment: It looks like Babel is still using the uncompiled JSX for some reason. Try removing `"type": "module"` and `"esmodules": true`

Comment: `"type": "module"` and `"esmodules": true` removed and the original error shows up :/. Do you know why it happens on my machines (tried on 3 different machines with different OSes), but not in codesandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-wiles-cunm1 ?

Comment: I can't figure out how to fix your Mocha config. Code Sandbox works because it's using Jest which automatically supports Babel, so I'd recommend switching from Mocha to Jest.